# Twitter API 1.1 on Older Mac Systems

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm maintaining an app that is required to support Macs running 10.5 and above. With Twitter's switch to version 1.1 of their API I've been unable to locate a solid library that supports these older systems.

I've tried STTwitter, oauthconsumer, and gtm-oauth to no avail.

My only requirement is that I be able to GET three tweets from a user's public timeline. I was previously using this end point :

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?exclude_replies=true&count=10&screen_name=%@", [_prefs objectForKey:@"twitterHandle"]];
```

Is it time to kick my 10.5.x users to the curb?

Comment: Why not back port one of those libraries?  You seem to be excluding the possibility of forking their respective repositories and actually modifying the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X 10.5 comes installed with Ruby. You can call the ruby gem "twurl" (using a command line call and parsing the results).

Plenty of example are available here: https://github.com/marcel/twurl

I used something like this for a Python project before the popular Python libraries had been updated to support API v1.1.

Good luck!

Comment: Python tweepy module is working fine with API v1.1 http://pythonhosted.org/tweepy/html/